# How can the Hadwiger–Nelson problem depend on the axioms of set theory?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

The [wikipedia page on the Hadwiger Nelson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) says the following two things:

> The correct value may actually depend on the choice of axioms for set theory.

and

> the problem is equivalent (under the assumption of the axiom of choice) to that of finding the largest possible chromatic number of a finite unit distance graph.

Assuming we take the axiom of choice as a given, this latter remark makes the problem sounds like a combinatorial problem - not one that you would expect to depend on foundational issues. Is it really possible that two different models of ZFC could contain distinct finite subgraphs of the unit distance graph?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be taking the axiom of choice as given, and the "choice of axioms for set theory" the first quote is referring to is exactly about the axiom of choice.

Comment: Maybe you're right; I assumed that was referring to axioms beyond ZFC, because most mathematicians take choice for granted.

Comment: I think the wording in the Wikipedia article is too strong, because (exactly as you said) when people talk about things depending on the axioms for set theory they typically mean axioms *beyond* ZFC rather than axioms already included in ZFC.

Comment: Are you sure that whether a given graph is unit-distance is a purely combinatorial matter? A priori, verifying that a unit-distance drawing exists could involve guessing all sorts of strange angles.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course I'm not sure; it just seems unlikely to me. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Hmm, okay -- I seem to have missed your last sentence. Sorry.

Comment: @HenningMakholm no worries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting the statement.

Any two well-founded models of ZF with the same ordinals will agree on the finite planar unit-distance graphs, and their chromatic numbers. This is due to the **Shoenfield absoluteness theorem**. (Actually, much more is true - if I'm not missing something, any two models of ZF with the correct $\omega$ should agree on the finite planar unit-distance graphs and their chromatic numbers.)

However, the axiom of choice is required to show that the maximum of these numbers is indeed the chromatic number of the plane! In the absence of choice, these two numbers don't have to be the same.

---

Here's a sketch of how to prove that the chromatic number of the plane is the maximum of the chromatic numbers of the finite unit-distance graphs, assuming choice. We'll actually prove a stronger result: that an arbitrary graph is $k$-colorable iff all of its finite subgraphs are $k$-colorable (this is the **Erdos-de Bruijn theorem**).

We use ultrafilters (we don't have to, but they're fun). Suppose $G$ is a graph; let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of finite subgraphs of $G$, and suppose every $F\in\mathcal{F}$ is $k$-colorable. Fix, for each $F\in\mathcal{F}$, a $k$-coloring $c_F$ of $F$. Now let $\mathcal{U}$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathcal{F}$ such that, for each $F\in\mathcal{F}$, the set $\{G\in\mathcal{F}: F\subseteq G\}$ is in $\mathcal{U}$ (such an ultrafilter exists since the family of such sets has the finite intersection property).

Now let $\chi$ the "ultralimit" of the $c_F$s along $\mathcal{U}$: for an edge $e\in G$, set $\chi(e)=i$ iff $\mathcal{U}$-many colorings $c_F$ have $c_F(e)=i$. It's not hard to verify that this is in fact a $k$-coloring of $G$.

(Strictly speaking, this only shows that the chromatic number of the plane is *at most* $k$, but the other inequality is immediate.)

Comment: Thanks! I would appreciate a bit more certainty on the parenthesized remark about models of ZF with the right $\omega$, but I'll go ahead and accept your answer anyway.

Comment: It will be very hard to show that "a maximal element of $\mathbb P$ must be a $k$-coloring of the plane." There must be a counterexample, but it will be easier to give a counterexample to the analogous statement in one dimension. The chromatic number of the *line* is $k=2.$ If $D=\{0,2\}$ and $p(0)\ne p(2),$ then $(D,p)$ can not be extended to a $2$-coloring of the plane.

Comment: @bof Quite right, fixed.

Comment: The proof of the [Erdős–De Bruijn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)) (for finite $k$ a graph is $k$-colorable if every finite subgraph is $k$-colorable) is not hard, but it's not just "take a maximal proper coloring"; instead, use an ultrafilter, or the compactness theorem, or Rado's selection principle, or the Tychonoff product theorem.

Comment: @bof: How about a model-theoretic argument instead? Make a theory with uncountably many atomic propositions of the form "the point $(x,y)$ has color $k$", and axioms to ensure that every point has exactly one color and points at unit distance have different colors. If this theory does not have a model, it is inconsistent, so by compactness there's a finite inconsistent theory, which corresponds to a finite unit-distance graph with too high chromatic number. (This still need choice, to prove the completeness theorem for uncountable vocabularies).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, that's one way to prove the Erdős–De Bruijn theorem; that's what I meant by "the compactness theorem" in my last comment. More simply (IMO) use compactness of the Tychonoff product of copies of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ (discrete topoology) indexed by vertices of the graph.

Comment: A similar model-theoretic argument allows us to extend the 4-color theorem (for coloring the edges of any finite planar graph) to 4-coloring the edges of any infinite planar graph.

Comment: @user254665 Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $G$ be ***any*** graph—an infinite planar graph, or the unit-distance graph of the plane, or ***any other graph***. If every finite subgraph of $G$ is $k$-colorable, then $G$ itself is $k$-colorable. This is the statement of the Erdős–De Bruijn theorem which I mentioned in an earlier comment. And, as I also mentioned in that comment, the Erdős–De Bruijn theorem can be proved by an argument using the compactness theorem. (Although that is not the simplest or most natural way to prove it.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: it seems that 'edges' in "to 4-coloring the edges" in the comment at 2016-01-16 23:14:22Z should have been *vertices*, right? Obviously, not every planar graph is *edge*-4-colorable.